# Calling a method from DLL file to handle events C#

Tags: c#, oop, events, event-handling

I am new to OOP and I am building a C# library and need to call a method from my .dll file as button handler

For example, a developer can add the .dll file of my library to his project. he creates a button and instead of creating a method to handle the event he calls a method from my .dll file and pass its arguments. I imagine I will have something like the code below but could not have it running!

In my DLL I have class "Class1" as follow:

```
Class1
{
    private string _s;
    public Class1(string s)
    {
         this._s = s;
    }

    public static void MyMethod(Class1 c)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

in my current project I have:

```
MainClass
{
   Class1 c = new Class1();
   Button myButton = new button();
}
```

Now I want to call MyMethod from Class1 when myButton is clicked. I tried:

```
myButton.OnClick += MyDLLName.Class1.MyMethod(c);
```

I also tried:

```
myButton.OnClick += (s,e) => MyDLLName.Class1.MyMethod(c);
```

But it keeps giving me "Method name expected" error!

I don't want to create a handler method in my MainClass and call the MyMethod from Class1

Any idea?

Comment: What is `string` doing in `(s, e) => MyDLLName.MyClass.MyMethod(string s);`? That's not how you call a method - that's how you *declare* a method (at least the parameter list).

Comment: But it's *less* clear when you don't actually show the code you're trying to use. It's *still* unclear as you're providing the type name rather than the variable name. Please provide a [mcve] - it's very unclear what you're doing at the moment.

Comment: Hope it is clear now

Comment: Not really - it's still not a [mcve]. We should be able to copy, paste, compile and run. Also, `MyMethod` isn't a static method, so how do you expect to call it with just `MyDLLName.Class1.MyMethod`? You'd need to call it on an instance of `Class1`. First thing to sort out: check that this is *actually* related to this being in separate assemblies. Try the same code with everything in a single assembly and namespace. I suspect you'll have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you modify your MyMethod like below;

```
public static void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//do something here..
}
```

then you can use like this;

```
myButton.OnClick += MyDLLName.MyClass.MyMethod;
```

Comment: But I still need to pass arguments to the method?

Comment: Imagine that whenever you click the button, myButton component will always pull the same trigger. This means button will always try to pass sender and e parameters. So I strongly suggest you to write your custom methods according to these parameters. Then you can do whatever you want in your custom method anyway

Answer (score 0):

If your method has a different signature to that returned from firing the event you could just put a wrapper around it, like:

```
public static void WrapperMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDLLName.MyClass.MyMethod(sender.Tostring());
}

myButton.OnClick += WrapperMethod;
```

Also:

```
myButton.OnClick += (s,e) => MyDLLName.MyClass.MyMethod(s.toString());
```

should work - note that you don't define the type of the parameter in the method called - also if your method expects a string you need to convert s (which is an object) to a string in some way.